# WCF performance issue in Vista

Tags: wcf, performance, windows-vista, windows-xp, tcp

I am having performance issues with Vista when trying to connect with wsHttpBindings and NetNamedPipeBindings on Vista.

I'm having 4 WCF services where the first one connects to the second and the second one connect to two others.

The problem is when I run this setup on my Vista (64 bit) desktop the response times a really weird.

Laptop:
WsHttpBinding < 150 ms
NetNamedPipeBinding < 30 ms

Seems normal to me, but when I ran exact the same setup on the Vista computer the result where as following.

Desktop:
WsHttpBinding < 50 ms
NetNamedPipeBinding < 90ms

Which seems really weird because NetNamedPipeBinding should always be faster then http.

An other thing to note is that when I run the application in Debug mode it will use about 60% of the CPU (both cores)  on the laptop and about 15% of the CPU (also both cores) on the Desktop. I have no idea why.

The code where I connect to the webservices:

```
//On the first webservices connection to SubCall
public SubCallServiceClient client = new SubCallServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_ISubCallService");

//On the SubCall service connecting to Calls
private readonly CallsServiceClient callsClient = new CallsServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_ICallsService");

//On The SubCall service connecting to Subscription    
private readonly SubscriptionServiceClient subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_ISubscriptionService");
```

Does anyone know what this could be?

Here are the specs of the two systems

### Laptop

### System Information

Operating System: Windows XP Professional (5.1, Build 2600) Service Pack 3 (2600.xpsp_sp3_gdr.090804-1435)
System Manufacturer: Dell Inc.
System Model: MP061
BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A02
Processor: Genuine Intel(R) CPU           T2300  @ 1.66GHz (2 CPUs)
Memory: 2046MB RAM
Page File: 705MB used, 2723MB available
DirectX Version: DirectX 9.0c (4.09.0000.0904)
DxDiag Version: 5.03.2600.5512 32bit Unicode

.NET 3.5
Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition

Dekstop PC:

---

### System Information

Operating System: Windows Vista™ Business (6.0, Build 6001) Service Pack 1 (6001.vistasp1_ldr.090805-0102)
System Model: OptiPlex 760
BIOS: Phoenix ROM BIOS PLUS Version 1.10 A03
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz (2 CPUs), ~3.0GHz
Memory: 3930MB RAM
Page File: 1701MB used, 6337MB available
DirectX Version: DirectX 10
DxDiag Version: 6.00.6001.18000 32bit Unicode

.NET 3.5
Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition

Comment: Code where I Make the connection with the webservices:

public SubCallServiceClient client = new SubCallServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_ISubCallService");

private readonly CallsServiceClient callsClient = new CallsServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_ICallsService");

private readonly SubscriptionServiceClient subscriptionClient = new SubscriptionServiceClient("NetNamedPipeBinding_ISubscriptionService");

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an inconsistency in your question.

Is your laptop running Windows XP?

If yes: Windows XP does not have IIS 7 and WAS (Web Activation Serices)

IIS7/WAS is required to run WCF NetNamedPipeBinding.

Therefore, I think that the difference in the performance numbers is that: somewhere you are running a different binding than you think you are running.

Comment: My laptop is running Windows XP, though i'm not hosting the webservice on IIS. (or when I start debug it will run IIS automatically?) I will post the code where I make connections to the other webservices.